# Where is the rubymine embedded Web Preview?

Tags: rubymine, embedded-browser

Among the features the rubymine's page  mentions:

Context toolbar opening the page preview in a browser or in an embedded Web Preview.

I would like to have the web preview in the IDE, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a web preview, but it was removed from the product a long time ago because it had a lot of problems. Right now you have to use an external browser.